# Class template partial specialization: compiler error

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17, partial-specialization

This program

```
#include <iostream>

template <int I>
struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A<I>()\n"; }
};

template <int I>
struct A<I + 5>
{
    A() { std::cout << "A<I + 5>()\n"; }
};


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

is compiled neither by gcc HEAD 10.0.0 20190 nor by clang HEAD 10.0.0.

For example the gcc compiler issues error

```
prog.cc:10:8: error: template argument '(I + 5)' involves template parameter(s)
   10 | struct A<I + 5>
      |        ^~~~~~~~
```

Is there a wrong class template partial specialization?

Comment: I don't get what you expect the outcome to be... Can you elaborate what you are trying to accomplish and why this (in my eyes 100% reasonable) error confuses you?

Comment: @MaxLanghof Why is it a wrong class template partial specialization?

Comment: You might specialize only `A<numeric_limits<int>::min()>`, .., `A<numeric_limits<int>::min() + 4>`. :)

Answer (score 7):

This is not a valid partial specialization (though the error could be better). The clause we are not inline with is the following:

> **[temp.class.spec]**
>
> [8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.spec#8) Within the argument list of a class template partial
>   specialization, the following restrictions apply:
>
> - The specialization shall be more specialized than the primary template.

"The specialization is not more specialized!?" I suppose you think. But that is indeed the case. The rules for determining which is "more specialized" are described in [**[temp.class.order]**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.class.order). The gist of it is that we are to consider two hypothetical function template overloads:

```
template <int I>
struct A { /* ... */ };

template<int I>
void foo(A<I>); //1

template<int I>
void foo(A<I + 5>); //2
```

We then perform overload resolution and partial ordering of the function templates. If #2 wins, it's more specialized and your declaration is legal. If it doesn't win, the declaration is invalid. Partial ordering is done by cooking up some arguments and doing template argument deduction of one template against another. So suppose we start with comparing the first to the second (I'll rename them for simplicity, but they are still overloads):

```
void foo1(A<0>); -> void foo2(A<I + 5>);
```

Does the argument deduction succeed here? It doesn't. `I + 5` is a non-deduced context:

> **[temp.deduct.type]**
>
> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> [5.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.type#5.3) - A non-type template argument or an array bound in which a
>   subexpression references a template parameter.

The `I` references a template parameter, so `I + 5` is a non-deduced context. Therefore template argument deduction fails in this direction.

Let's try the other direction. Again we cook up an argument

```
void foo2(A<1 + 5>); = void foo2(A<6>);  -> void foo1(A<I>);
```

Deduction obviously succeeds here. So according to the rules of function template partial ordering, `foo1` is more specialized than `foo2`. This means that our primary is really more specialized than our "partial specialization", making the partial specialization ill-formed.

Comment: I really want to upvote because of the excellent explanation and presentation (and I assume that's what the other votes are for), but I still think this answer to the question isn't actually correct. The real issue is that deduction _always_ fails for the specialization, which makes the program explicitly ill-formed. That it's not more specialized than the primary template is a consequence in this case but not really the core problem.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - It could succeed and the program would still be ill-formed. That would be the situation where neither is more specialized (which too would violate the first quoted clause). So this is very much correct.

Comment: Sure, if the program in question were different. I guess my point is to explain the compiler message(s), which clearly pinpoint the issue at deduction failure, not lack of "specializedness". But I guess it's a moot point if the standard has overlapping reasons for ill-formedness, so have an upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

Looking into [temp.class.spec.match/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.spec#match-3), we have

> If the template arguments of a partial specialization cannot be deduced because of the structure of its *template-parameter-list* and the *template-id*, the program is ill-formed.

with the example

```
template <int I, int J> struct A {};
template <int I> struct A<I+5, I*2> {};     // error

template <int I> struct A<I, I> {};         // OK

template <int I, int J, int K> struct B {};
template <int I> struct B<I, I*2, 2> {};    // OK
```

Clang's error message echoes this:

> ```
> error: class template partial specialization contains a template parameter that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used
> ```

(See **@StoryTeller**'s answer for why this deduction fails in your code, I won't duplicate that here.)